# Tag Not defined for MsgType 110

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I am trying to get the security list response from the Fix Server using QuickFix4J, but I am getting following error :

<20230201-05:21:05, FIX.4.4:targetId->senderId, error> (Reject sent for message 2: Tag not defined for this message type, field=110)

Here's my request :

```
    private void getSecurityList(SessionID sessionID){

        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println("Sending security list request : >>>>>>>>>>> ");
        SecurityListRequest request = new SecurityListRequest();
        request.getHeader().setField(new MsgType(MsgType.SECURITY_LIST_REQUEST));
        request.getHeader().setField(new SenderCompID(senderId));
        request.getHeader().setField(new TargetCompID(targetCompanyId));

        request.set(new SecurityReqID(id));
        request.set(new SecurityListRequestType(SecurityListRequestType.ALL_SECURITIES));


        try {
            Session.sendToTarget(request);
        } catch (SessionNotFound e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

here's my FIX config :

```
[default]
FileStorePath=target/data/company
ConnectionType=initiator
SenderCompID=senderId
TargetCompID=targetId
SocketConnectHost=someurl.com
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=60
FileLogPath=logs-client
ResetOnLogon=Y
ForceResync=Y

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SocketConnectPort=62481
LogonTag=553=something
LogonTag1=554=something
```

Here's how I handle the response :

```
@EventListener
    public void handleFromApp(FromApp fromApp) throws FieldNotFound {

        System.out.println("From App : ");
        Message message = (Message) fromApp.getMessage();

        System.out.println("From App Message Type : " + message.getHeader().getString(MsgType.FIELD));
//        SessionID sessionID = fromApp.getSessionId();

        if (message instanceof MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh){
            MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh marketData = (MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh) message;
            orderBookService.getOrderBookFromFix(marketData);
        }

        if (message instanceof ExecutionReport){
            ExecutionReport executionReport = (ExecutionReport) message;
            newOrderService.handleOrderStatus(executionReport);
        }

        try {
            String msgType = message.getHeader().getString(MsgType.FIELD);
            System.out.println("Message Type : " + msgType);
            if (MsgType.SECURITY_LIST.equals(msgType)){
                System.out.println("Received security list response >>>> mapping now >>>>>>>> ");
                securityListResponseMapper(message);
            }
        } catch (FieldNotFound e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Response that I am logging before my client rejects it :

```
(8=FIX.4.4#9=2153#35=y#49=senderId#56=targetId#34=2#52=20230201-05:06:22.877#320=9b578bc4-9d00-4a3b-898d-3d649bf52612#322=111#560=0#146=60#55=ETH/USD_CFD#110=0.00000001#1208=0.01#55=BTC/USD_CFD#110=0.0001#1208=0.01#55=LTC/BTC#110=0.0001#1208=0.000001#55=WAXP/USC#110=0.000001#1208=0.000001#55=ETH/BTC#110=0.0001#1208=0.000001#55=TUSD/USC#110=0.01#1208=0.00001#55=LTC/USD_CFD#110=0.00000001#1208=0.01#55=DOGE/USC#110=0.1#1208=0.0001#55=LTC/USC#110=0.0001#1208=0.01#55=BCH/USC#110=0.0001#1208=0.01#55=XRP/JPY_CFD#110=1#1208=0.001#55=XRP/JPY#110=1#1208=0.001#55=XRP/USD_CFD#110=0.1#1208=0.0001#55=LTC/JPY_CFD#110=0.00000001#1208=1#55=LTC/JPY#110=0.00000001#1208=1#55=BCH/JPY#110=0.00000001#1208=1#55=BCH/USD_CFD#110=0.00000001#1208=0.01#55=ETH/JPY_CFD#110=0.00000001#1208=1#55=ETH/JPY#110=0.00000001#1208=1#55=DASH/USDC#110=0.00001#1208=0.01#55=ETH/USDC#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=LTC/USD#110=0.00000001#1208=0.01#55=BCH/USDC#110=0.0001#1208=0.01#55=BCH/JPY_CFD#110=0.00000001#1208=1#55=ETH/USD#110=0.00000001#1208=0.01#55=DASH/USD#110=0.00001#1208=0.01#55=PAX/USDC#110=0.01#1208=0.00001#55=PAXG/USDC#110=0.01#1208=0.00001#55=XRP/USDC#110=0.0001#1208=0.01#55=DOGE/USDC#110=0.1#1208=0.0001#55=BTC/UST#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=TUSD/USDC#110=0.01#1208=0.00001#55=BCH/UST#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=WAXP/USD#110=0.000001#1208=0.000001#55=DASH/USDT#110=0.00001#1208=0.01#55=USDT/USD#110=0.01#1208=0.00001#55=PAXG/USC#110=0.01#1208=0.00001#55=XRP/USDT#110=100#1208=0.00001#55=LTC/USDC#110=0.0001#1208=0.01#55=USDC/USD#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=DOGE/USDT#110=0.1#1208=0.0001#55=ALGO/USD#110=0.1#1208=0.0001#55=BTC/USD#110=0.00000001#1208=0.01#55=BTC/JPY#110=0.00000001#1208=1#55=LTC/UST#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=DOGE/USD#110=0.1#1208=0.0001#55=BTC/USDT#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=BTC/USDC#110=0.00001#1208=0.01#55=BCH/USD#110=0.00000001#1208=0.01#55=ETH/USDT#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=ETH/UST#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=BCH/USDT#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=PAX/USC#110=0.01#1208=0.00001#55=DASH/USC#110=0.00001#1208=0.01#55=BTC/USC#110=0.00001#1208=0.01#55=XRP/UST#110=100#1208=0.00001#55=LTC/USDT#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=ETH/USC#110=0.01#1208=0.01#55=XRP/USC#110=0.0001#1208=0.01#55=BTC/JPY_CFD#110=0.00000001#1208=1#10=249#)
```

Image of PDF doc, how the response is structured from the broker.

[image]

Comment: So that tag is probably not defined on the message. Did you check the spec of the counter party?

Comment: Yes,I did check. They have tag 110 in group 146. Updating my question with the image from the PDF doc broker has provided, and also the response that is logged, but yet my FIX client is rejecting it.

Comment: Why doesn't your config have any DataDictionary information?

Comment: Grant is right, you need to use a data dictionary to correctly parse repeating groups.

Comment: Working with FIX very first time, what would be the right place to understand data dictionary configuration ?

Comment: https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html

Comment: @Gladiator9120 I'm assuming we are using the same broker and I have the same issue with a different tag. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos Yes, I sort of ended up customizing entire FIX44.XML using trial and error method, for every error I get, I update the XML file and at last the error was resolved.